# Ranking log-linear distributions and the Lucas numbers

Tags: distributions, power-law, log-linear, ranks

The wikipedia page on [rank-size distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93size_distribution) [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93size_distribution#:%7E:text=When%20any%20log%2Dlinear%20factor%20is%20ranked%2C%20the%20ranks%20follow%20the%20Lucas%20numbers%2C%20which%20consist%20of%20the%20sequentially%20additive%20numbers%201%2C%203%2C%204%2C%207%2C%2011%2C%2018%2C%2029%2C%2047%2C%2076%2C%20123%2C%20199%2C%20etc.):

> "When any log-linear factor is ranked, the ranks follow the Lucas numbers, which consist of the sequentially additive numbers 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, etc."

I can't find any sources for this claim. What is the relationship between log-linear distributions and Lucas numbers?